# Sending a MIME email prepared beforehand (in PHP or Python)

Tags: php, python, email

Is it possible to send a MIME message as it is, without adding any headers? For example, if I have a correct MIME message with all headers and content saved to a text file, is it possible to use the contents of this file without modification and send it via SMTP?
Apparently both python's SMTP.sendmail and PHP smtp::mail require at least "To:" and "From:", and passing the complete message to these functions doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) that python's `SMTP.sendmail` should take a sender, a set of recipients, and a verbatim MIME message like the one you have.  (The split here between the sender/recipients and the message itself is because you're talking SMTP.  The [SMTP envelope determines the actual recipients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.3) and is actually [independent of the message payload](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-1.1).)  So you should be good to go with `SMTP.sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

You could read up to the first blank line, use those as additional headers, then send the rest in the body.